# Find max indices along z axis of numpy 3d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 3d numpy array. I'd like to find the largest coordinate at each [x,y] grid point of non-zero elements along the z axis of the array. This would result in a 2d array filled with z index values.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `amax` function in Numpy, and specify the axis along which you want the maximum to be taken:

```
ans = numpy.amax(arr_3D, axis=2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  amax doesn't give me what I want since I want the z-index of the max value.  However, I have since found np.argmax which gives me just that.  The only problem is that it doesn't ignore nan's and when it finds one, it returns its index as the location of the max value.  I could probably change all the nan's to a very small number and then run np.argmax but it seems there should be a less kludgy way to do this.

Comment: In case anyone else comes across this, you may want `np.nanargmax`. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nanargmax.html